# Speed up Join tables

Tags: mysql, join

Working to join 3 tables i manage to get my results when joining the first two:

```
SELECT so.id, so.title, so.cat, sr.img
FROM extended_details AS so
JOIN details AS sr ON so.id = sr.id
LIMIT 6
```

The problem comes when i try to join a third table like so:

```
SELECT so.id, so.title, so.cat, sr.img
FROM extended_details AS so
JOIN details AS sr ON so.id = sr.id
JOIN scores AS se ON sr.id = se.id 
ORDER BY score_sec DESC
LIMIT 6
```

This seems to take forever and i never get my results, each table have around 300k ids and i've tried correlated subqueries but i'm afraid this could take longer.

The problem seems to be at ORDER BY since running

```
SELECT so.id, so.title, so.cat, sr.img, se.score
        FROM extended_details AS so
        JOIN details AS sr ON so.id
        JOIN scores AS se ON se.id = sr.id
        LIMIT 6
```

does not have a problem.

Comment: indexing the tables and use explain command

Comment: The first query also has no `ORDER BY`. Maybe that's causing the slowdown.

Comment: Do you really want to join on the `id` columns of all the tables? If that's the primary key of each table, they're not usually related to each other.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `score_sec` column?

Comment: @Barmar ids are the same on all three tables, this is created at insert and in this case score_sec index is se.id... i'm reading more about EXPLAIN but just now the gave me results after about 5 minutes... no bueno

Comment: Is there a 1-to-1 relationship between the tables?

Comment: @Barmar there is... but running a query to confirm this, my last table, scores, took 12 seconds with 250k rows... maybe there's something there. Digging into that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of detail in the question, no information about primary keys, unique or other indexes...

We suspect the absence of suitable indexes is causing a very inefficient execution plan.

---

Suggestions:

- Add some appropriate indexes.
- Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan for the query.
- Without a suitable index, the `ORDER BY col` is going to require a "Using filesort" operation on a (reportedly) large set.
- the LIMIT clause is applied as nearly the last step, after the entire resultset is sorted.